# Angular - In custom service after calling $http service and updating array value, its not updated outside the function

Tags: service

I created the custom service where I have empty array which is updated from json value which i called using $http service. But when I called that new array it doesn't give me updated array instead it gives me empty array.

But when i called the service from some other controller it gives me correct value.

```
service('categoryTree', ['$http', function($http) {
var categories = [];
$http.get('/json/categories.json').then(function (response) {
    response.data.forEach(function (category) {
        categories.push(category);

    });
});
console.log(categories);//it gives empty array here
// I am trying to create a new function through this categories array value but it shows empty


return {
    categories: categories
};
```

}])

Can somebody help me. Thanks a lot.